# Why do all my rows in an ODBC 18 Linked Azure SQL Table show as deleted

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

why is the driver mis-identifying my primary key? the primary key on the table is a GUID but it's mis-identifying the primary key as a BIGINT that is converted to a string. As a result, all of the rows show as #DELETED#. Is there a way around this? The BIGINT column is indexed in SQLServer as a unique index, but it is not the Primary Key

Comment: What is field type  your  GUID in this table? I'll use ``uniqueidentifier`` in earlier version of SQL server.

Comment: You need to provide more details

Comment: Are you perhaps using an older version of Microsoft Access and there are `datetime` or `datetime2` data types in the linked table? Ref: [Access linked table to SQL Server database returns "#Deleted"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/access-linked-table-deleted)

Comment: yes a guid is a uniqueidentifier/replicationid in Access. Yes there are datetime values in the table. I should note that before adding the bigint value to the SQL table Access worked correctly. And Access is the most recent version

Comment: I am using the most current version of Access. The Primary Key is defined as replication id in MSAccess or uniqueidentifier in SQL. There is a unique index on the bigint column which apparently is confusing access in table design mode it still shows the uniqueidentifier as the primary key.

Comment: My Access version (2010) has the same behavior  if  column <Id> is ``BIGINT``. If this column is ``Int``, works correctly.  I see, in my version <Bigint> type not allowed. In linked table, <Bigint> column converted to (linked as) <text(255)>. If you use GUID column as unique field for linking Access thru ODBC with SQL Server table, works correctly too.